# How can I fix the `Event Listener` problem when I update the shop table in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, observer-pattern

### Now I need to send message to User whose shop is activated. And also give them a dashboard to add new products.

> **Goal:** When in `shops` table the value of column `is_active` is made to `active` from `inactive` then I need to fire the email to user.

`Shop.php`

```php
public function seller()    //user --> seller
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}
```

> I need observer class so I can find all these information on documentation in event section of Eloquent.

### Step 1

Run below command to Create observer class for Shop Model

```
~$ php artisan make:observer ShopObserver --model=Shop
```

- Now we have `DealOcean\app\Observers\ShopObserver.php`

`ShopObserver.php`

```php
<?php

namespace App\Observers;

use App\Shop;

class ShopObserver
{
    /**
     * Handle the shop "created" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Shop  $shop
     * @return void
     */
    public function created(Shop $shop)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the shop "updated" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Shop  $shop
     * @return void
     */
    public function updated(Shop $shop)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the shop "deleted" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Shop  $shop
     * @return void
     */
    public function deleted(Shop $shop)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the shop "restored" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Shop  $shop
     * @return void
     */
    public function restored(Shop $shop)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Handle the shop "force deleted" event.
     *
     * @param  \App\Shop  $shop
     * @return void
     */
    public function forceDeleted(Shop $shop)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

### Step 2

Before doing that, we need to tell Laravel that you need to use this class whenever model events related to Shop is updated. To register an observer, use the observe method on the model you wish to observe. You may register observers in the boot method of one of your service providers. In this example, we'll register the observer in the AppServiceProvider:

Go to `AppServiceProvider`

`AppServiceProvider.php`

```php
use App\Shop;
use App\Observers\ShopObserver;
```

```php
public function boot()
{
    Shop::observe(ShopObserver::class);
}
```

### Step 3

`ShopObserver.php`

```php
public function updated(Shop $shop)
{
    dd($shop);
}
```

> SO when I update the `is_active` column to `active` from `inactive` then this doesn't work.

> I mean the it should call the `update` function. But this function is not called.

> I can't figure out the problem.

`ShopController.php`

```php
public function update(Request $request, Shop $shop)
    {
        Shop::where('id', $request->shop_id)
            ->update([
                'is_active' => $request->is_active,
                'description' => $request->description,
                'location_id' => $request->location
            ]);

        return Redirect::route('dashboard.shops');
    }
```

Comment: How do you updating it in code (controller)? Edit question with that code of how user/application sets `is_active` field to `active`.

Comment: I have added that method in last section. Have a look bro....

Comment: I need to enter the update method observer first.

Comment: I don't think accepted answer solves your main question and that is "to check if is_active field has been changed to active". I made an answer of how just that can be achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the docs, this is called mass update because the models are not retrieved so events are not fired. You should find the shop first then update its details like this.

```
$updatingShop = Shop::where('id', $request->shop_id)->first();

if($updatingShop) {
   $updatingShop->update([
            'is_active' => $request->is_active,
            'description' => $request->description,
            'location_id' => $request->location
        ]);
}
```

Comment: I can update this.... but problem is after update the update function in ShopObserver is not getting fired up

Comment: Bro. It works... but one more problem. If i update only is_active field then didnt fired. But when i uodate is_active and description then update observer fired up... but i want only for is_active field

Comment: Model observer for update only fired if the value is different than what it was originally stored. So if you update the model without changing any value, the event won't be called. Are you sure you updated a new value?

Comment: oh i see. Bro... now the is_active is not updating the way you suggest.... others are updating......

Comment: Did you put is_active as a fillable property in the model?

Comment: Now ok bro.... i didnt add 'is_active' in 'fillable'

Comment: No problem, you should add those columns as fillable if you want to update or create using the Laravel mass assignment method. Read it here bro, https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: But one questions why it was not working when i update the way i use in ShopController?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218759/discussion-between-syazany-and-imrul-hasan).

Comment: @user14009834 With this solution you'll get wrong behavior when updating shop's properties other than `is_active`. Check my answer bellow.

Answer (score 0):

In `updated` method of observer you can compare old value with new value.
Also, my suggestion would be to use [event/listener methodology](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/events) there so you can have something similar to this:

```
/**
 * Handle the User "updated" event.
 *
 * @param  \App\Shop  $shop
 * @return void
 */
public function updated(Shop $shop)
{
    if ($shop->is_active === 'active' 
        && $shop->is_active !== $shop->getOriginal('is_active')) {

        // you can make quick and dirty way here
        // but correct and well done job would be if you set event/listener
        event(new ShopUpdatedToActive());
    }
}
```

You can always check old values with some of methods from [this trait](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php) (`isDirty`, `isClean`, `wasChanged`, `hasChanges`, `getOriginal` etc.)

Comment: You can see in that code that is made check if old and new attribute of `is_active` are different which means that attribute has been updated and also if new updated value is `active`. In that case, in that if block you can put code of sending email but again, better to do that with event/listener handler to have code nicely decoupled.

Answer (score -1):

Do you update the `Shop` model or the `User` model? Pay attention, you subscribed to the `Shop` model.

Advice:
Try to avoid Observers, as they introduce some `magic` to the requests flow.
I prefer to use Events and Event Listeners to do such a job.
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/events

Comment: Yes I am updating the Shop model. OK THANKS for your suggestion. After fixing this... then i will use the system you suggest

Comment: Concept of observers and concept of event\listener don't exclude each other. You want to use observer for one thing and event/listener for completely different thing. It's more than common to have event call in observer method.

Answer (score -1):

just use the `$shop` in your controller `update` method to update

```
public function update(Request $request, Shop $shop)
{
    $shop
        ->update([
            'is_active' => $request->is_active,
            'description' => $request->description,
            'location_id' => $request->location
        ]);

    return Redirect::route('dashboard.shops');
}
```

this will fire the `observer` class

the problem that you are using where on the model it self and that is a mass update, that will not fire the observer

#edit
if you want the observe to work only on the `is_active` field
you should edit
in your observe class add that:

```
public function updated(Shop $shop)
{
  if($shop->isDirty('is_active')){
    // add your code
  }
}
```